# how to update dom based on date in reactjs using Jquery?

Tags: reactjs

I have a script which I would like to do a transition in when the reducer state changes. When the state changes it removes the loading overlay. My aim is to ease the dom slowly in when that overlay goes away and displays the content.

Once done loading opacity should be 1 before opacity should be 0.

I was attempting to use the reference to add and remove properties within the mainContent but unsuccessful. I was hoping there is a way to do this possible that I may have overlooked.

```
.mainContent {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 200ms opacity ease-in-out;
}
```

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { contentHeader } from "../contentHeader";
import { contentBody } from "../contentBody";
import { contentFooter } from "../contentFooter";
import LoadingOverlay from 'react-loading-overlay';
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

class contentLayoutComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        document.body.classList.add("content");
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.classList.remove("content");
    }

    render() {
        const { left, right, loading } = this.props;
        var contentBody = <LoadingOverlay
                        active={loading}
                        spinner
                        text='Loading...'
                        >
            <contentBody className="mainContent" ref="mainContent" left={left} right={right}>{this.props.children}
                    </contentBody></LoadingOverlay>;

        return (
            <div id="main" className="container-fluid">
                {loading &&
                    <Helmet>                    
                    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/loading.ico" />
                    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/icon8-loading-50.png" />
                    </Helmet>
                } else {
                    <Helmet>
                        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
                    </Helmet>                    
                }
                <contentHeader />
                {contentBody}
                <contentFooter />
            </div>

        );
    }
}

contentLayoutComponent.propTypes = {
    left: PropTypes.element,
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
    right: PropTypes.element
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {

    };
}

const contentLayout = connect(mapStateToProps)(contentLayoutComponent);
export { contentLayout };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend setting the opacity directly on the body component, this way your css will take care of the transition and you don't have to make extra classes

```js
class contentLayoutComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        document.body.classList.add("content");
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.classList.remove("content");
    }

    render() {
        const { left, right, loading } = this.props;
        return (
            <div id="main" className="container-fluid">
                {
                    // This is more readable
                    loading
                        ? (
                            <Helmet>
                                <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/loading.ico" />
                                <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/icon8-loading-50.png" />
                            </Helmet>
                        )
                        : (
                            <Helmet>
                                <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
                            </Helmet>
                        )
                }
                <contentHeader />
                <LoadingOverlay
                    active={loading}
                    spinner
                    text='Loading...'
                >
                    {/* Setting opacity with loading context */}
                    <contentBody className="mainContent" ref="mainContent" left={left} right={right} style={{ opacity: loading ? 0 : 1 }}>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </contentBody>
                </LoadingOverlay>
                <contentFooter />
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Your css

```css
.mainContent {
    transition: 200ms opacity ease-in-out;
}
```

Also, avoid using the same variable name

EDIT: Remember to add the 'style' prop to your contentBody component

contentBody.js

```
return (
  <div style={props.style}>
    {props.children}
  </div>
```

Comment: For some reason, the content in the background is still showing under the overlay as before.

Comment: @robdigm forgot to mention that you need to add the style prop to your contentBody component, I edited my answer